# Не удалять вопросы, за которые выдан знак Реверс

Tags: обсуждение, знаки, удаление-вопросов

Вот описание знака [Реверс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal):

> Дать ответ с рейтингом +20 баллов на вопрос с рейтингом −5 баллов. Знак можно получать многократно.

Вполне логично, что вопрос с рейтингом -5 может оказаться далеко не лучшим, но, возможно, ради столь высоко оценённого ответа стоит его сохранить?

К тому же, есть вероятность (часть знаков работают по такому принципу, конкретно про этот не уверен), что удаление скажется на получении следующего знака, т. е. заработанные знаки участник не потеряет, но и новые получать не будет до тех пор, пока количество вопросов не сойдётся.

Comment: А есть прецеденты?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну вообще-то я надеялся, что отвечающие сами заглянут в список по ссылке и заметят, что из 6 таких вопросов удалён [только этот](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/180049/178988) :)

Comment: Похожее предложение на Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge

Comment: Так это КМ удалил. С ним и надо беседы вести. Мета - это же не сборник правил, как мы выяснили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так я ж спрашиваю в принципе ;)

Comment: @defaultlocale, какой-то мутный вопрос. Он вроде ссылки на вопросы просит, хотя они на странице знака все есть. Надо просто 10К заработать?

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему, плюсы(минусы?)/знаки за ответы не должны пропадать ни при каких обстоятельствах. Если они есть - значит ответ помог.
На счет самих вопросов/ответов - лично я могу придумать реальные ситуации, когда удалять надо. Так что такое...